# Prove that for all $m \in \Bbb R$, there exists $y\in \Bbb R$ st $m\cos y = \sin y$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

I'm trying to show that for all $m\in \Bbb R$, there exists  $y\in\Bbb R$ st $m\cos y = \sin y$. MVT occurred to me but that gives $\cos(c)$ for some random $c$ so that doesn't help, and I looked at the definition but that introduces complex numbers and I don't see any way to make progress there. So how do I show this (if it is, in fact, true)?

Comment: What happens if you divide both sides of the desired equation by $\cos y$?

Comment: @GregMartin Lol I'm dumb, great point thanks

Comment: You're not dumb—everything's easier in hindsight!

Comment: @GregMartin Haha thanks, true